# where to define body styles

Tags: css, sass, bourbon, neat

I'm having this issue where I can't seem to override the background color of the body element in my Neat Bourbon website.

I defined the background color like this in the _layout.scss file:

```
body {
background: lighten($brokenwhite, 5);
}
```

but when I check the element in Chrome Devtools, the background color of the body element is still defined as 'white'.

So where can I define the background color of the body element?

My source repository is [available here](https://github.com/acandael/colloquium).

Comment: Have you tried, `background: lighten($brokenwhite, 5) !important;`?

Comment: I don't see a background line in your main.css, but then there's ton of other css files. Set up a JSFiddle with the relevant example so that we can provide better advice.

Comment: I believe the "background" field is for setting the background as an image file, have you tried using "background-color:"?

Comment: @Hashem Qolami: I added the !important rule, but when I check in Chrome devtools, the background-color attribute for the body element is now: white !important;

Comment: @Toontje Actually I didn't ask to do that :) BTW, I'm curious to know the value of `$brokenwhite`?

Answer (score 2):

I guess that `$brokenwhite` color is so bright, hence SASS compiler returns `white` as the result.

For instance:

```css
$brokenwhite: #eee;

body {
  background: lighten($brokenwhite, 10);
}
```

The result would be:

```css
body {
  background: white;
}
```

You could use **[SassMeister](http://sassmeister.com/)** online tool to compile the above example.

Comment: **FYI:** The actual color is [`#f8f9fc`](https://github.com/acandael/colloquium/blob/master/stylesheets/base/_colors.scss), So `lighten(#f8f9fc, 5)` would be `white`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your SASS is just not compiling, 
Have try changing it to this maybe .

```
body {
background: lighten($brokenwhite, 5%);
}
```

Just added the '%' after the 5. Also make sure that $brokenwhite is a defined variable.

Maybe save what ever sass file this _layout.scss is being imported to just in case ( although it should do this automatically )

Hope this helps.

Comment: It doesn't need to add `%` after the number.

Comment: Okay - I dont think the SASS is compiling, as i dont see either pieces of code from the _layout.scss inside the main.css file.

Comment: NVM, i do see the code now - @hashem-qolami your answer is correct i believe.